# How to get text field values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following HTML/JS code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type='text' id='action' placeholder='defualt'>
<button type='button' onclick='document.getElementById("action").placeholder="it worked!"'>Change Placeholder</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When the button is pressed, the `placeholder` value of the `action` `text` `input` field is set to 'it worked!'

What I would like to do is make the script set the `placeholder` of the field whatever the user puts into it when the user presses the button. How should I do this?

Comment: Have you attempted this first? Based on your code (using `document.getElementById`) it appears you would know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the input element's value, you can access `.value` property. Then just like you set the placeholder, you can assign that to `.placeholder` property.

Finally, if you wish to have the placeholder visible immediately, you can reset the value by setting it to an empty string.

```js
function setPlaceHolder() {
  var input= document.getElementById("action");
  input.placeholder=input.value;
  input.value = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type='text' id='action' placeholder='defualt'>
  <button type='button' onclick='setPlaceHolder();'>Change Placeholder</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
function myfns() {

var x = document.getElementById("action").value;
console.log(x)

  document.getElementById("action").placeholder = x
  
  document.getElementById("action").value = "";

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type='text' id='action' placeholder='defualt'>
  <button type='button' onclick='myfns()'>Change Placeholder</button>
</body>

</html>
```